# Which generic parameter must be specified?

Tags: generics, rust

I encountered an issue where I have this trait (some things omitted):

```
use rand::Rng;
pub trait GeneticAlgorithm<R, Ins, C> : Clone where R: Rng {
    fn call<F>(&self, program: F) where F: FnOnce(&C);
}
```

This struct implements the trait:

```
pub struct Mep<Ins> {
    instructions: Vec<Ins>,
    unit_mutate_size: usize,
    crossover_points: usize,
}

impl<R, Ins> GeneticAlgorithm<R, Ins, Vec<Ins>> for Mep<Ins> where R: Rng, Ins: Clone {
    fn call<F>(&self, program: F) where F: FnOnce(&Vec<Ins>) {
        program(&self.instructions);
    }
}
```

In a test I attempt to run this:

```
let mut rng = Isaac64Rng::from_seed(&[1, 2, 3, 4]);
let (a, b) = {
    let mut clos = || Mep::new(3, 3, rng.gen_iter::<u32>().map(|x| x % 10).take(10));
    (clos(), clos())
};
let mut c = Mep::mate((&a, &b), &mut rng);
c.call(|x: &Vec<u32>| panic!());
```

Rust claims that it cannot infer a type somewhere, but I am not sure how to specify the type of a closure if that is the issue, nor am I able to identify which specific generic parameter is causing the issue:

```
error: unable to infer enough type information about `_`; type annotations or generic parameter binding required [E0282]
c.call(|x: &Vec<u32>| panic!());
```

Which generic parameter is necessary to specify?

If anyone would like to build the code itself, I am [hosting it on GitHub](https://github.com/vadixidav/gpi).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at your declaration, trimmed a bit for clarity:

```
pub trait GeneticAlgorithm<R, Ins, C> {
    fn call<F>(&self, program: F);
}
```

There are 4 generic types here: `R`, `Ins`, `C`, and `F`. Now, let's look at your implementation (again, trimmed):

```
impl<R, Ins> GeneticAlgorithm<R, Ins, Vec<Ins>> for Mep<Ins> {
    fn call<F>(&self, program: F);
}
```

So, you have now provided a concrete value to `C` that depends on `Ins`. You still have 3 parameters that the user has to specify: `Ins`, `F`, and `R`.

`F` will be specified when the function is called, based on the closure type. `Ins` will be specified when the `Mep` structure is created.

That leaves `R`. *Based on these declarations*, what is `R` supposed to be? It's impossible to tell. This appears to just be an error in your implementation; it's likely that you should have it somewhere. The other option is that you simply have a parameter that you *don't need*.